# Send Email From Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i want to write a script where I can send an email where the body will be the a cell value from the sheet

```
function sendemail()  {
MailApp.sendEmail("email address", "subject", "body");
}
```

the above code work but the only issue I'm facing to make "body" refer to the Cell from where data will be copied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple code you can try

```
function sendemail()  {
let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
let sh = ss.getSheetByName("the name of the sheet");

let emailbody = ss.getRange("").getValue();

MailApp.sendEmail("email address", "subject", emailbody);
}
```

Replace the `"name of the sheet"` with the actual name of the Sheet in your spreadsheet
and insert the Cell reference to `ss.getRange("")` (Example: `ss.getRange("A1")`) to indicate the cell that has the message body you like GAS to use when sending the email.

This is considering that your script is [bound to the Spreadsheet file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound). If if is not, then you have to manually call and store the Spreadsheet file before running any of the script above.